# How to execute '~copyResources' in background while also executing 'run'

Tags: sbt

We have a web project based upon Unfiltered/Finagle/Netty. When developing locally, we would like to run two SBT commands at once:

- `run` to run a local server to test against
- `~copyResources` in the background, so that changes to JS and CSS resources are visible to the running webapp

Thus far, I've tried the following without success

- Setting run to fork via `fork in run := true`, and then invoking both via `;run;~copyResources`. The problem seems to be that the running sub-process cannot receive input from the SBT console, so we can't shut it down at the right time.
- Setting ~copyResources to fork via `fork in copyResources := true`, and then invoking both via `;~copyResources;run`. The run command doesn't start until copyResources is interrupted.
- Trying to run the 2 tasks concurrently via something like `all run copyResources`. I get back an error message `Cannot mix input tasks with plain tasks/settings`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the [sbt-revolver plugin](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver). I have created a [little sample project setup](https://github.com/reikje/sbt-run-copy-resources) which is using [Undertow](http://undertow.io/) and [Handlebars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java). Clone it then inside the project folder do:

```
> sbt
> re-start
> [press enter]
> ~copyResources
```

Open `http://localhost:7070/foo` then modify template.hbs and reload. It should work similar for your Unfiltered/Finagle setup. How do you like Unfiltered on top of Finagle? We tried Finatra for a bit but didn't like it that much.

Note: when you execute `re-start` you can see this message:

```
[info] Application sbt-run-copy-resources not yet started
[info] Starting application sbt-run-copy-resources in the background ...
```

which kind of indicates that resources are automatically copied by the plugin. This didn't work for me with the handlebars templates at least so the extra `~copyResources` was required.